# Toggle input disabled attribute using jQuery

Tags: jquery, toggle, attr

Here is my code:

```
$("#product1 :checkbox").click(function(){
    $(this)
        .closest('tr') // Find the parent row.
            .find(":input[type='text']") // Find text elements in that row.
                .attr('disabled',false).toggleClass('disabled') // Enable them.
                .end() // Go back to the row.
            .siblings() // Get its siblings
                .find(":input[type='text']") // Find text elements in those rows.
                .attr('disabled',true).removeClass('disabled'); // Disable them.
});
```

How do I toggle `.attr('disabled',false);`?

I can't seem to find it on Google.

Comment: Any reason why you can't use the disabled property of the field? `$("input").get(0).disabled = isFalse;` // http://jsfiddle.net/uAfhj/

Comment: I found the [DependsOn](https://github.com/dstreet/dependsOn) plugin which you might find useful

Answer (score 516, accepted):

```
$('#el').prop('disabled', (i, v) => !v);
```

The **[`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)** method gets the value of a property for the first element in the set of matched elements.

###### Arguments

- Property **`name`** (e.g. `disabled`, `checked`, `selected`) anything that can either be true or false
- Property **`value`**, can be:

  - `(empty)` returns the current value.
  - `boolean` sets the property value.
- **`function`** Is called for each matched element, the returned value is used to set the property. There are two arguments passed; the first argument is the *index* (number, starting with 0, increases for each found element). The second argument is the current *value* of the element (true/false).

So in this case, I used a function that supplied me the index (`i`) and the current value (`v`), then I returned the opposite of the current value, so the property state is reversed.

###### Additional information

The `.prop()` method gets the property value for only the *first* element in the matched set. It returns undefined for the value of a property that has not been set, or if the matched set has no elements. To get the value for each element individually, use a looping construct such as jQuery's `.each()` or `.map()` method.

###### Attributes vs. Properties

The difference between attributes and properties can be important in specific situations. Before jQuery 1.6, the `.attr()` method sometimes took property values into account when retrieving some attributes, which could cause inconsistent behavior. As of jQuery 1.6, the `.prop()` method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while `.attr()` retrieves attributes.

Comment: As an update, this looks very neat using arrow functions: `$('#el').prop('disabled', (i, v) => !v);`

Answer (score 104):

I *guess* to get full browser comparability `disabled` should set by the value `disabled` or get removed!
Here is a small plugin that I've just made:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.toggleDisabled = function() {
        return this.each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            if ($this.attr('disabled')) $this.removeAttr('disabled');
            else $this.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

[Example link](http://jsfiddle.net/ifaour/SHynr/1/).

EDIT: updated the example link/code to maintaining chainability!
EDIT 2:
Based on @lonesomeday comment, here's an enhanced version:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.toggleDisabled = function(){
        return this.each(function(){
            this.disabled = !this.disabled;
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: This may work, but it's going to be slow, because you're constantly creating new jQuery objects. `$.fn.toggleDisabled = function(){ return this.each(function(){ this.disabled = !this.disabled; });}` is all you need.

Comment: @lonesomeday: I was going to post this but I *tend* to think that this is not the correct way to set/unset `disabled` attribute. Anyway, if you can confirm that this is a cross-browser solution..I will update my answer.

Comment: For any future googlers, this solution works equally well for the attribute 'required'.

Comment: `prop` is the better method since 1.6 as said by Arne.

Comment: No, I don't suggest to do like this, prop is better

Answer (score 22):

```
    $('#checkbox').click(function(){
        $('#submit').attr('disabled', !$(this).attr('checked'));
    });
```

Comment: Note: only works below jQuery 1.6. Use .prop() instead of attr() on both occurences to get boolean values back. See http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: @ManuelArwedSchmidt Not right. Think you don't understand the difference between `attr` and `prop` yet.

Answer (score 11):

Another simple option that updates on a click of the checkbox.

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox/>
<input disabled type="submit" id="item"/>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#checkbox').click(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $('#item').prop('disabled', false); // If checked enable item       
    } else {
        $('#item').prop('disabled', true); // If checked disable item                   
    }
});
```

In action: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/unequalsine/e3acqdef/)

Comment: Get rid of the `if` block with `$('#item').prop('disabled', this.checked);`

Answer (score 3):

Quite a while later, and thanks to @arne, I created this similar small function to handle where the input should be disabled AND hidden, or enabled AND shown:

```
function toggleInputState(el, on) {
  // 'on' = true(visible) or false(hidden)
  // If a field is to be shown, enable it; if hidden, disable it.
  // Disabling will prevent the field's value from being submitted
  $(el).prop('disabled', !on).toggle(on);
}
```

Then a jQuery object (such as $('input[name="something"]') ) is simply switched using:

```
toggleInputState(myElement, myBoolean)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly simple with the callback syntax of [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
$("#product1 :checkbox").click(function(){
  $(this)
   .closest('tr') // find the parent row
       .find(":input[type='text']") // find text elements in that row
           .attr('disabled',function(idx, oldAttr) {
               return !oldAttr; // invert disabled value
           })
           .toggleClass('disabled') // enable them
       .end() // go back to the row
       .siblings() // get its siblings
           .find(":input[type='text']") // find text elements in those rows
               .attr('disabled',function(idx, oldAttr) {
                   return !oldAttr; // invert disabled value
               })
               .removeClass('disabled'); // disable them
});
```