# How to toggle attribute in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use images as checkboxes. The following would work fine if it were radios instead of checkboxes that I was targeting but with checkboxes the problem is I can't select an element by clicking on it again after selecting it.

```
// image checkbox
$('#imageCheckBoxes img').click(function() {
    $(this).parent('span').find('input:checkbox').attr('checked', 'checked');
});
```

```html
<div id="imageCheckBoxes">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Africa</a>  <span><img src="images/checkbox-inactive.png" /><input type="checkbox" name="" value="" /></span>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Asia/Pacific Islands</a>  <span><img src="images/checkbox-inactive.png" /><input type="checkbox" name="" value="" /></span>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Australia</a>  <span><img src="images/checkbox-inactive.png" /><input type="checkbox" name="" value="" /></span>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Central/South America</a>  <span><img src="images/checkbox-inactive.png" /><input type="checkbox" name="" value="" /></span>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Europe/Russia</a>  <span><img src="images/checkbox-inactive.png" /><input type="checkbox" name="" value="" /></span>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">North America</a>  <span><img src="images/checkbox-inactive.png" /><input type="checkbox" name="" value="" /></span>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">United Kingdom</a>  <span><img src="images/checkbox-inactive.png" /><input type="checkbox" name="" value="" /></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I need to basically toggle the check `attr()` part.

How to do that?

Comment: Use a `<label>` tag around the contents in the `<li>` would be the simplest way to do this. No JS required

Comment: Very similar for `disabled`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702000/toggle-input-disabled-attribute-using-jquery

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I'd do this by passing a function to `prop` (since jQuery 1.6, `attr` before). The return value of this is set as the new property value.

```
$(this)
    .closest('li')
        .find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', function(idx, oldProp) {
            return !oldProp;
        });
```

The key fact here is that you can pass `true` or `false` to `prop` to set the `checked` property.  `oldProp` is the existing value of the property (which will be either `true` or `false`), so `!oldProp` is the inversion: checked elements are unchecked and vice versa.

Note that I have also changed your code to look for the closest ancestor `li` element with [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest), which should be more reliable and effective.

Comment: hmm not working. Using your code I can still select the checkboxes like before but when I click a second time the checked boxes don't get unchecked.

Comment: Ahh ok, reason why it wasn't working earlier was because I swapped the checkbox image in a part of the code I ommited here so when $(this) was being clicked again it was no longer the same image. Thanks working now.

Comment: If the structure is always like this, `$(this).next()` will work too.

Comment: I ended up using jquery's `toggleClass()` for my purposes. However, I too liked your solution.

Comment: +1. AH! A callback function for 'prop' second parameter is SO neat! Brilliant answer. I've refactored my if-else right away :)

Answer (score 4):

You could add a rather basic jQuery extension, that works in the same way as "toggle()" and "toggle(showOrHide)" but for attributes - "toggleAttr(attribute)" and "toggleAttr(attribute, addOrRemove)"

```
$.fn.toggleAttr = function(a, b) {
    var c = (b === undefined);
    return this.each(function() {
        if((c && !$(this).is("["+a+"]")) || (!c && b)) $(this).attr(a,a);
        else $(this).removeAttr(a);
    });
};
```

Note, this is xhtml compatible, and is designed for attributes such as "disabled", "enabled", "checked", "selected" and so on.

Example of use (for your scenario):

```
$('#imageCheckBoxes img').click(function() {
    $(this).parent('span').find('input:checkbox').toggleAttr('checked');
}
```

EDIT - though as pointed out by artlung - a label is probably best for your scenario

Comment: Nice. Making an extension for it, makes the rest of the code more readable.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible approach:

```
$('#imageCheckBoxes').delegate('img', 'click', function(){
    var $associatedCheckbox = $(this).siblings('input:checkbox');
    if ($associatedCheckbox.is(':checked')){
        $(this).removeClass('checked');
        $associatedCheckbox.removeAttr('checked');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('checked');
        $associatedCheckbox.attr('checked', 'checked');
    }
});
```

I'm using `delegate()`, though you could just as easily use your standard `click()` or a `bind()` call to add the listening function.

I also have added some code to add a class to the image. If you, say, wanted to give visual feedback to the user, you could implement that with your `.checked` class on those images.

```
#imageCheckboxes img {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
}
/* feedback for your users! */
#imageCheckboxes img.checked {
  border: 2px solid #6f6;
}
```

Now, it strikes me that you could also avoid JavaScript for this, and simple put `<label>` tags around your images, and then associate them with your checkboxes to get the same effect. Just replace your `<span>`s in your html with `<label>`.

Comment: Using `label`s is probably the best idea. +1 for that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$('#imageCheckBoxes img').click(function() {
    var el = $(this).parent('span').find('input:checkbox');
    if(el.is(':checked'))
        el.attr('checked', '');
    else
        el.attr('checked', 'checked');
});
```

Comment: *"I need to basically toggle the check attr() part."* I don't see how you address that issue... you just provide an alternative way to select the elements. But the original selector works fine as well.

Comment: You are right. I just updated the answer. My bad, thanks for catching my mistake.

Comment: The Ternary operator makes for shorter code: 
el.attr('checked',(el.is(':checked'))?'':'checked');

Answer (score 0):

My solution was a little more clever:

```
var $formContainer = $(".form-container"),
    $myCheckbox = $formContainer.find(".my-checkbox"),
    $requiredFields = $formContainer.find("input[required], textarea[required], select[required]").removeAttr("required"); // remove the required attribute on all required form inputs
$myCheckbox.change(function () {
    $formContainer.toggle("fast", function() {
        if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
            $requiredFields.attr("required", true);
        }
        else {
            $requiredFields.removeAttr("required");
        }
    });
});
```