# Button won't re-enable it self using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't figure out why my button won't re-enable when another button is clicked. Any help will be most appreciated

My code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnAdd').click(function() { 
        // enable the "remove" button
        $('#btnDele').attr('disabled','');
    }
});
```

demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/ATzBA/2/

Comment: im assuming the lack of a second `}` is a typo?

Comment: try using removeAttr() instead of setting the attribute's value to an empty string

Comment: @MrOBrian Don't use `removeAttr` on native properties, because once you do, they're gone and you cant work with them again till DOM refresh.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I've used `removeAttr` before for just this purpose and it works great in all browsers I've tested.  If the element needs to be disabled again, a simple `attr('disabled', 'disabled')` adds the property back to the element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 $('#btnDele').attr('disabled',false);
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

You could also try `$("#btnDele").removeAttr('disabled');`

Answer (score 3):

The prop function is the ***correct*** way to do this in JQuery.

```
$('#btnDele').prop('disabled', false); //enabled
$('#btnDele').prop('disabled', true); //disabled
$('#btnDele').prop('disabled'); //returns true if disabled, false if enabled.
```

See documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Comment: +1 for using prop.  Don't forget to mention it's for jQuery 1.6+

Comment: Cheers @wirey - forgot it was a recent addition!

Answer (score 2):

The "disabled" attr has to be removed completely, not just set to null/an empty string. You need to use jQuery's `removeAttr()`:

```
$(function(){
     $('#btnAdd').click(function(e){
          $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
      });
 });
```

Somebody talks about it/browser compatibility issues here: [Toggle input disabled attribute using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702000/jquery-toggle-input-disabled-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the .attr function I'd use Jquery UI and use $('#btnDele').button("enable");
http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Button#methods

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#btnAdd').click(function() {

```
        // to enable the "remove" button
        // set 'disabled to false'
        $('#btnDele').attr('disabled','false');
```

});
});