# How to disable anchor tag after first click in javascript ?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, thickbox

I have a *a href* tag with css class thickbox I need to disable the link after first click. how I can do this?

Aspx code

```
<a href="SomePage.aspx?FDID=11&KeepThis=true&TB_iframe=true&height=150&width=400"
     onclick="return DoSomething(this)" class="thickbox" id="AnchorID">
<img id="MyImageButton" alt="Image" src="SiteImages/image.png" runat="server" />
</a>
```

My JavaScript Method

```
function DoSomething(element) {

                return true;
            }
```

Comment: make a var firstclick =true;outside from the function and in Dosomething add    
firstclick=false ;
or same technique in codebehind
let me know if it doesnt work

Comment: after first click means first time it will work and then becomes disable ?

Comment: @Steve, I will do, but all answers didn't helped me. thats why.

Comment: @WaqarJanjua yes the same first i want to call the method then becomes disable the link.

Comment: @niknowj, sorry, I'm coming into this conversation late - but if you return `true` from `DoSomething()` then is the page not going to navigate to the `href` page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your javascript you can set the attribute `disabled=""` at your element. (look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4702086/394028))

If, with disable, you mean to not let the browser go to the url, you have to call `event.preventDefault()` (look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1164654/394028))

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to create a hidden feild which will store a value example 1 or 0. If the user clicks the link first time set the hidden feild value to 1 and allow the user to redirect and then disable the hyperlink. If user again clicks the hyper link then first check the hidden feild if it contains a value 1 then don't allow him to redirect. Hope you understand my point. Also set the href property in the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what the OP is trying to do, but if it is purely to allow the script to run the once after clicking, something like this would work...

```
function DoSomething(element) {
  if(element.getAttribute("block")==null){
    ...
    element.setAttribute("block","1");
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

This has the advantage of not changing the style of button by setting the `disabled` attribute.

However, returning `true` from the function and then in turn returning `true` to the `OnClick` handler of the link will result in the browser navigating to the URL in `href`... so I can't see why the need for the blocking of a 2nd run. (Unless `thickbox`, which I know nothing about, works in a way which is not the normal.)