# jQuery 1.10.2, enable/disable elements, a bit tunning

Tags: jquery

There is a lot written about **enabling/disabling** elements by **jQuery**, but I have a little confusion. I try to use a select and a single input field, if select is used, the field have to be disabled and vice versa.

For example

```
  <span>Choice a year from the list</span>
  <select id="selYear" name="selYear" >
        <option id="op-0">Choice a year</option>
        <option id="op-1" >1893      </option>
        <option id="op-2" >1894</option> 
  </select>
  <span>Or type a new one</span>
  <input id="year_single" name="year_single" type="text" >
```

(Of course there must be a input filter.)
To disable the input field and enable it, if the first option is chosen was easy. If some body inquires how, there is the code:

```
  $("#selYear").change(function() {
    if(this[0].selected){           
        $("#year_single").attr("disabled",false);   
    }       
    else  
    $("#year_single").attr("disabled",true)   

})
  )
```

But the opposite case works not how I expected.
I tried:

```
    $("#year_single").change(function() {
    if($(this).val().length == 0){
        //alert("aaa");
        $("#selYear").attr("disabled",false);   
    }       
    else  
    $("#selYear").attr("disabled",true)   

})
```

This works, but the select becomes disabled after pressing Insert key, or after clicking on it, I expected to be disabled exactly after first inserted digit in it.
Probably the `change()` function isn't the right choice in such a case?

Comment: Use `.prop()` not `.attr()`. As the [docs state](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), "To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the .prop() method."

Comment: The insert key doesn't disabled the select here: http://jsfiddle.net/URPmz/. What browser are you testing with? Also, `prop` should be used for native properties.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Toggle input disabled attribute using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702000/toggle-input-disabled-attribute-using-jquery)

Comment: Indeed, `change` is not the appropriate event as it is deferred until the text input loses focus ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/change/)). You could use a keyboard event like `keyup`, but then the user could still paste in text using the mouse without triggering your event handler (right click > Paste).

Comment: @Rory McCrossan - Firefox and Google Chrome. I don;t know why the Insert key works in this way. So, I changed attr to prop an used the advice from Nikolaj Zander and  Mattias Buelens. Now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

try to use the onkeyup event instead

```
$("#year_single").on("keyup", function(event){
   //YOUR CODE
});
```

Comment: Thanks! The better way!

Answer (score 0):

For **your jquery version** > **1.6** and [`.keypress`](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) event

```
$("#year_single").keypress(function() {
        if(this[0].selected){           
            $("#year_single").prop("disabled",false);   
        }       
        else{  
          $("#year_single").prop("disabled",true)   
        }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery .keypress() probably be of work for you:

```
 $("#year_single").keypress(function() {
    if($(this).val().length == 0){
        //alert("aaa");
        $("#selYear").attr("disabled",false);   
    }       
    else  
    $("#selYear").attr("disabled",true)   

})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you using jQuery 1.6+

```
$("input").prop('disabled', true);
$("input").prop('disabled', false);
```

if you are using jQuery 1.5 and below

```
$("input").attr('disabled','disabled');
```

To enable again

```
$("input").removeAttr('disabled');
```