# jQuery animation callback function won't change the attribute

Tags: jquery

I have the following function:

```
function carousel_go_right($container, pos_width){
    $container.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $container.animate({
        left: '-=' + pos_width
    }, 500, function() {
        $container.attr('disabled', '');
    });
}
```

The problem is that the "disabled" attribute does not change to "" after the animation is done.
I also tried `$(this).attr('disabled', '')` and it still doesn't work.

`console.log($container.attr('disabled'))` in the callback function shows the right value

Comment: Try to set disabled to false.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Toggle input disabled attribute using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702000/toggle-input-disabled-attribute-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should treat `disabled` as a [property, not an attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr):

```
$container.prop('disabled',false);
```

http://api.jquery.com/prop