# Enable/disable input field after second click

Tags: jquery, input, disabled-input

First I display a div container with disabled input fields.

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $(".disable-input").prop('disabled', true);
})
```

And with a second button inside the displayed div container I want to enable the change for input fields after the first click and after the second one the enabled input fields should be disabled. For example: Display my customers via div container and inside this div container I can change them with a click on the button. What is my mistake?

```
var count = 0;
    if(count == 0) {
         $("#edit").click(function(){
            $(".disable-input").prop('disabled', false);})  
            count = 1;
    }
    if(count == 1) {
         $("edit").click(function(){
                $(".disable-input").prop('disabled', true);})
                count = 0;
    }
```

Comment: you should handle the count checks on the inside of the handler. otherwise

Comment: possible duplicate of [Toggle input disabled attribute using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702000/toggle-input-disabled-attribute-using-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use attr('disabled', 'disabled') and removeAttr('disabled') to do this

```
var count = 0;
    if(count == 0) {
         $("#edit").click(function(){
            $(".disable-input").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            count = 1;
         });
    }
    if(count == 1) {
         $("edit").click(function(){
             $(".disable-input").removeAttr('disabled');
             count = 0;
         });
    }
```

The reason is that the presence of the 'disabled' attribute (regardless of value) on an input element is enough to cause the input to be disabled, whatever the value - i.e

```
<input type="text" disabled="false" />
```

...is disabled.

Comment: Is there the same procedure to show and hide textareas and div containers?