# Disable W3.CSS Hover Dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, w3.css

I have the typical W3.CSS hover dropdown, but I want it disabled until ready:

```
<div id="A" class="w3-dropdown-hover" style="width: 100%;">
    <button id="B" disabled class="w3-button" style="width: 100%;">Hover To Open</button>
    <div id="C" class="w3-dropdown-content w3-bar-block w3-border" style="width: 100%;">
        <p>2B</p>
        <p>|| !2B</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see I have put the `disabled` on the `button` and it looks disabled as you would expect.

**But** the dropdown still appears when I hover. I do not want that. I only want the dropdown to open when the button is not disabled.

You obviously cannot put the `disabled` on `C`, because the `disabled` only works on things like `button`s, `input`s, etc.

**Where do I put the `disabled`?**

**When I am ready in my javascript, how do I remove/reapply the `disabled`? By that I mean, on which of "A", "B" or "C" do I apply the jQuery `$("#A_Letter").prop('disabled', false);`**

Edit: the only thing I can think of is put `disabled` on the button and momentarily change the class of "A" to `w3-dropdown-click`.

Comment: `display: none` / `pointer-events: none;`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I want the user to know it is there, so I do not want it hidden, I just want it greyed and disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd apply some css to 'disable' the [pointer events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) so your browser won't detect any hover actions:

```html
<div id="A" class="w3-dropdown-hover" style="width: 100%; pointer-events: none;">
```

Demo Snippet:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/w3-css/4.1.0/w3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="A" class="w3-dropdown-hover" style="width: 100%; pointer-events: none;">
    <button id="B" disabled class="w3-button" style="width: 100%;">Hover To Open</button>
    <div id="C" class="w3-dropdown-content w3-bar-block w3-border" style="width: 100%;">
        <p>2B</p>
        <p>|| !2B</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

> When I am ready in my javascript, how do I remove/reapply the disabled

For the automatically toggling both states, we can:

- Move the `pointer-events:none` to a CSS class so we can use [`toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)
- Use the `prop` to [toggle the disabled state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702000/toggle-input-disabled-attribute-using-jquery)

```js
function toggle() {
  $("#A").toggleClass('disabled-hover');
  $('#B').prop('disabled', (i, v) => !v);
}
```

```css
.disabled-hover {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/w3-css/4.1.0/w3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="A" class="w3-dropdown-hover disabled-hover" style="width: 100%;">
    <button id="B" disabled class="w3-button" style="width: 100%;">Hover To Open</button>
    <div id="C" class="w3-dropdown-content w3-bar-block w3-border" style="width: 100%;">
        <p>2B</p>
        <p>|| !2B</p>
    </div>
</div>

<button onclick='toggle()'>Toggle Disabled</button>
```

Comment: Yep, `pointer-events` worked. Thanks for that. I'll also put the `disabled` on `"B"` so it is visually clear to the user. Thanks.